# Simplify the expression with metric tensor

Tags: metric-spaces, tensors

[image]

I have a very long-expression with metric tensor. How to simplify it? What is the key point to simplify?

Comment: Use that $g^{is}g_{sj}=\delta^i_j$, $(g^{is}g_{sj})_{,k}=0$ and Leibniz rule in this last equation

Comment: This is all one equation(expression). In which raw?

Comment: if you use Leibniz in $(g^{is}g_{sj})_{,k}=0$, you gotta get $g^{is}(g_{sj,k})+(g^{is}{}_{,k})g_{sj}=0$, then use it along your calculations